# How to make a CGPath without Fill?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, sprite-kit, cgpath

Im trying to make an SKShapeNode with no fill, and i can't find a way to make the cgpath just with the lines i draw, i made this by adding a fill color and trying to use other cgpath parameter to see if it didn't fill but it docent work, the target here is to make an skshapenode just with the context the user draw, then assign a physics body just to the lines or shapes the user has drawn.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   touch1 = [touches anyObject];
   location1 = [touch1 locationInNode:self];

    pathTodraw = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathTodraw, nil, location1.x, location1.y);



    sprite = [SKShapeNode node];

    sprite.path = pathTodraw;


    NSArray *colors = @[[UIColor blackColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor cyanColor]];
    NSUInteger colorindex = arc4random() %colors.count;

    sprite.strokeColor =[UIColor blueColor];
    sprite.lineWidth = 3.0f;
    sprite.fillColor = [colors objectAtIndex:colorindex];


    [self addChild:sprite];




}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   touch2 = [touches anyObject];

    location2 = [touch2 locationInNode:self];

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTodraw, nil, location2.x, location2.y);





    sprite.path = pathTodraw;


}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:pathTodraw];
    sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    sprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;

}
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if([self children].count>5){

    SKAction *remove = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:2.0],[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:1.0],[SKAction removeFromParent]]];

    [sprite runAction:remove];

        [self removeAllChildren];




    }
}
```

Comment: Why Are you setting the fill color to anything not transparent when you don't want the SKShapeNode to fill the path?

Answer (score 0):

If `SKShapeNode` is treating the path your provide as something to fill, then you need to provide a path that, when filled, produces the line you want. That's exactly what `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath()` does. It takes a path and a bunch of line-drawing control parameters, determines the shape that you'd get by stroking that path with those parameters, and creates a new path which, when filled, produces that same shape.